# What is the use of valMHome in mvn.cmd scripts

Tags: maven

I was going through the mvn.cmd script (in maven/bin) noticed that `valMHome` is not defined.

In old mvn.cmd `(maven 3.3.3)` it was like,

```
:chkMHome
if not "%M2_HOME%"=="" goto valMHome

SET "M2_HOME=%~dp0.."
if not "%M2_HOME%"=="" goto valMHome

echo.
echo Error: M2_HOME not found in your environment. >&2
echo Please set the M2_HOME variable in your environment to match the >&2
echo location of the Maven installation. >&2
echo.
goto error

:valMHome

:stripMHome
if not "_%M2_HOME:~-1%"=="_\" goto checkMCmd
set "M2_HOME=%M2_HOME:~0,-1%"
goto stripMHome
```

And in the latest mvn.cmd files `(maven 3.5.2)` it is like,

```
:chkMHome
set "MAVEN_HOME=%~dp0.."
if not "%MAVEN_HOME%"=="" goto valMHome
goto error

:valMHome

:stripMHome
if not "_%MAVEN_HOME:~-1%"=="_\" goto checkMCmd
set "MAVEN_HOME=%MAVEN_HOME:~0,-1%"
goto stripMHome
```

Any idea what is the role and use of `valMHome` in these scripts ?

Comment: It looks like this `valMHome` has been lost it's meanings during the removal of `M2_HOME` elimination. but from the context point of view it makes sense..but from logical it can be removed and the `stripMHome` could be used instead...Apart from that how have you been noticed that `valMHome` is not defined ? How have you called Maven? and which exact version are you using?

Comment: @khmarbaise First part is from maven 3.3 and the second snippet is from maven 3.5, I just wanted to know how they handle the things after the removal of M2_HOME, that is why I was seeking into these.

Comment: What do you mean by `how they handle the things after the removal of `M2_HOME`? The simple answer to this: No handling of M2_HOME anymore not needed etc. Only path entry is needed or calling it directly from bin directory...

Comment: @khmarbaise then why did they use the M2_HOME var in their scripts at the first place. Anyway for your statement "It looks like this valMHome has been lost it's meanings during the removal of M2_HOME elimination" , no it the first code snippet was from maven 3.3, Just wanted to now why earlier we wanted to set an additional env variable, and why now they don't want it and what changed in the mvn.cmd.

Comment: M2_HOME was coming from early history (Maven 2, 3.0.X, 3.1.X, 3.2.X, 3.3.X) but over the time we have learned that it produced more errors than it helps. [The support for M2_HOME has been removed](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.0-beta-1/release-notes.html). The variable MAVEN_HOME is only for internal use. In earlier days you could have used M2_HOME to set a the home of the Maven installation which works over different Maven versions but that has failed sometimes based on some changes (handling bootstrap etc.) and that was finally the reason to remove it.

Comment: Created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6332 for it...Thanks for finding this.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the information and glad the question helped to improve it as well.